# export mysql database table contents on to a PDF file using php

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdf

How to export MySQL database table contents on to a PDF file. It has to be displayed in the website as `download/print data`. When the customer click on that he/she has to get the PDF opened or an option to download the PDF with all the contents of the table using php.

Comment: I've used fpdf in the past. It's probably a little out of date but it's dead easy to use, and the website provides a number of useful  examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at http://www.tcpdf.org/. I never heard about out of box way to print mysql table data into PDF, but with TCPDF you can programmatically build a PDF file with table filled with data inside it. It also allows to output document created on the fly easily into a browser.

Answer (score 3):

```
    <?php
require('fpdf17/fpdf.php');
$pdf=new FPDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',10);
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->SetFont('times','B',10);
$pdf->Cell(25,7,"Stud ID");
$pdf->Cell(30,7,"Student Name");
$pdf->Cell(40,7,"Address");
$pdf->Cell(30,7,"Class");
$pdf->Cell(30,7,"Phone No");
$pdf->Cell(30,7,"E-mail");
$pdf->Ln();
$pdf->Cell(450,7,"----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
$pdf->Ln();

        include ('db.php');
        $sql = "SELECT studid,name,address,class,phone,email FROM studinfo";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $studid = $rows[0];
            $name = $rows[1];
            $address = $rows[2];
            $class = $rows[3];
            $phone = $rows[4];
            $email = $rows[5];
            $pdf->Cell(25,7,$studid);
            $pdf->Cell(30,7,$name);
            $pdf->Cell(40,7,$address);
            $pdf->Cell(30,7,$class);
            $pdf->Cell(30,7,$phone);
            $pdf->Cell(30,7,$email); 
            $pdf->Ln(); 
        }
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, it is always better if you can provide a description of what the issue was and how your answer solves it. This is a suggestion for further improving this and future answers.

Answer (score 2):

You should make use of PDF creator libraries like:

1. [**FPDF**](http://www.fpdf.org/)
2. [**TCPDF**](http://www.tcpdf.org/)
3. [**EzPDF**](http://pubsvn.ez.no/doxygen/4.0/html/classeZPDF.html)

All three are easy to learn in the order I've put. The documentation of FPDF and EzPDF are very neat and clean. But TCPDF Documentation is not that readable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://www.tcpdf.org/ to create your own PDF. The `examples` and the doc tabs will help you ^^ (http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html for all the methods)

You can create a HTML table will all your data and put it in your PDF using the `WriteHTML()` method.